# Save a variable with the time a process has been opened

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need a script that closes some programs that have been opened for too long. I'm having trouble saving into a variable the time (in seconds) that a process has been opened. The conflicting line is:

```
SECONDS_OPENED=$(ps -p $pid -o etime=) | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3  }' ;
```

or the one that looks alike below. If i put:

```
echo $(ps -p $pid -o etime=) | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3  }' ;
```

It prints correctly. I don't know why, in the first case, i don't know why, `SECONDS_OPENED` is still null.

The relevant code is below. If i can add anything, let me know it.

```
TIME_OPENED=$(ps -p $PID -o etime=) ;
SECONDS=$TIME_OPENED | awk -F: '{ print $3 }' ;
if [[ "$SECONDS" != "" ]] ;
then 
SECONDS_OPENED=$(ps -p $pid -o etime=) | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3  }' ;
else 
SECONDS_OPENED=$(ps -p $pid -o etime=) | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 60) + $2  }' ;
```

Comment: what is the `)` after `etime=`? It is breaking th ecommand.

Comment: it's closing the ( that begun after =$(

Comment: but it does not make any sense if you are then piping to `awk`. Just do `SECONDS_OPENED=$(ps -p $pid -o etime= | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3  }'`. That is, without this `)` after `etime=`.

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH. Now i get it. It worked perfectly. Thank you, and sorry for bringing this kind of mistake.

Comment: No problem :) I added it as an answer. You can accept it to show that your issue is already solved.

Answer (score 1):

You were writing the following:

```
SECONDS_OPENED=$(ps -p $pid -o etime=) | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3  }' ;
                ^____________________^ ^
                                       this becomes orphan
```

so that the command was executed just partially.

To store all the command `ps -p ... | awk '...'`, just wrap everything within the `$()` expression:

```
SECONDS_OPENED=$(ps -p $pid -o etime= | awk -F: '{ print ...  }')
                ^_______________________________________________^
```